Why do I get "No data found for this domain and memberId." for some members who have data using the LinkedIn MemberSnapshot API?
I am using LinkedIn MemberSnapshot API and I receive the data for some of the members from domain INBOX but the same script return
{
  "error": "Client error: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData?q=criteria&domain=INBOX` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:\n{\"message\":\"No data found for this domain and memberId.\",\"status\":404}\n"
}

for other members who have a lot of connections and messages. I do receive the CONNECTIONS data for the same members through the api.
The url I am using is
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData
$headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
            'LinkedIn-Version' => '202312',
        ];

$params = [
                'q' => 'criteria',
            ];

$response = $client->get($url, $params);

I also try using start=0, start=1 ...etc because sometimes the data is not returned on start=0.
I expect to receive the data from the domain for this member, instead I get "No data found for this domain and memberId."
For the same member I get data from some domains but not from others.
What is the reason why this works for some members and not for others when they all have connections and messages or data that should be returned and I successfully receive data from other domains for them?

Hello, I do have the exact same problem. Did you figured it out ?
